# PostGIS: Select Certain Columns returns Blanks

Tags: postgis

So I have a pretty stupid question. Suppose I have a table of the US called `us_states`. I created two new tables called `wy_test` which is created using

`CREATE TABLE wy_test AS SELECT * from us_states where state = 'Wyoming';`

AND  `wy_test2` using the query

`CREATE TABLE wy_test2 AS SELECT gid, geom from us_states where state = 'Wyoming';`

However when I export the two tables using `pgsql2shp` and open it in QGIS, the table from `wy_test` will show me the state of Wyoming while `wy_test2` will return blank.

Why does this occur? And how can I query the table so that I can pick specific columns without getting a blank in return?

Comment: QGIS will not show any shape unless there is some kind of id field defined. Please show the pgsql2shp command you are running. Does gid exist in wy_test2? You can always create a dummy field with pgsql2shp, using something like `SELECT row_number() over() as id, geom FROM wy_test2` in the SQL expression.